# permission groups not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, permissions, membership

ok, I have set up a basic membership system where I have groups in my db (members, admin and moderator).
the groups have 3 fields, id, name and permission. members I have left permission blank, admin has {"admin": 1
"moderator": 1} and moderator has {"moderator": 1}.

I have a simple function in a `user.php` file in a folder `classes`

**function**

```
 class User {
        public function hasPermission($key) {
        $group = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id = ?", array($this->data()->group));

        if($group->count()) {
            $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);

            if($permissions[$key] === 1) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }   
}
```

then in a file `admin.php` I have a simple bit of code that should show a echo if the users logged in is admin

*ps: I have required the `init.php` file that has my `classes/User.php` file required so that I do not need to call several files.*

**code**

```
<?php
}

if($user->hasPermission('admin')) {
        echo '<p>You are a admin!</p>';

    } else {
    echo 'You need to <a href="login.php">log in</a> or <a href="register.php">register</a>!';
    }

?>
```

from this when a admin is logged in a echo should be displayed, unfortunately I am just getting a blank page.

**Question**

So my question is dose anyone know why this is not working as I have a admin permission set user logged in and am getting nothing on `admin.php`?

***groups table***
[image]

***users table***
[image]

Ok so for some reason the You need to log in or register! echo shows it dose not recognise when a admin is logged in.

all im trying to do is allow different groups different page accsess

Comment: We need to see the code that's building `$user`

Comment: I see an unneeded `}` before `else`

Comment: Ok I will amend the extra } and add the $user code to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, since my previous answer was deleted.. here's another go.

Your problem is the type-safe comparison you do here:

```
if($permissions[$key] === true) {
    return true;
}
```

Your array is filled from a json object `{"moderator": 1}`, which translates to `array('moderator' => 1)` in php. You are comparing a boolean `true` with an integer `1` using a type-safe comparison. That will fail because the types do not match. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php for more detail.

You can remedy this by either using type-unsafe comparisons or by converting your `$permissions` to booleans.

```
if ((bool)$permissions[$key] === true) // Both are now of type boolean and will be compared.
```

or

```
if ($permissions[$key] == true) // Will compare 1 and TRUE, which will result in TRUE.
```

Comment: Could you give some more information about the contents of those variables? Do some var_dumps of `$permissions`, so that you can see what you're actually comparing to. While you're at it, also make sure you're getting past the `if($group->count()) {` part.

Comment: Do me a favor and update the if($group->count()){ part with this:
`if($group->count()) {
            $permissions = $group->first()->permissions;
            var_dump($permissions);
            $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);
            var_dump($permissions);
            var_dump($permissions[$key]);
            if($permissions[$key] === 1) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            echo "No group results!";
        }`

Now execute it and post the output please.

Comment: Thank you for your help. it was a small spelling error in the end... my bad, thanks for your help.